# How can I use a php script to generate actions that are executed at certain intervals

Tags: php, cron

i am developing an application and 1 want to set a certain php script to run every 10 minutes using the cpanel cron job.

```
*/10 * * * * php /path/to/my/site/cronjobs/index.php
```

But now, here's the part that's more of concern to me, because on the index.php file, i want to write a function that separates the actions based on the results in milliseconds from a timeserver.

for example,

- every 30 mins (3*10mins), i want index.php to run query A
- every 50 mins (5*10mins), i want index.php to run query B
- every 10 days(10*24*6*10mins), i want index.php to run query C
- every 20 hours(20*6*10mins), i want index.php to run query D
- every 12 hours(10*6*10mins), thats like at midnight and 12noon, i want it to run query E

if you notice they are all fall within the range, 10 minutes cron execution time but i'm not certain on how to go about this, whether to read from the milliseconds of a timeserver or write my own function which i feel is the wrong approach.

Comment: Pass a variable to the cronjobs. `/path/to/my/site/cronjobs/index.php?query=A` etc. And use multiple cronjobs to make your life easier.

Comment: hmm, the idea is to have one job, and a script that handles lots of actions instead. rather than having more than one jobs registered on the cpanel.

Comment: It's easier to have multiple cronjobs and one script handle all of the requests. Trying to do it all in one cronjob and then trying to time it with milliseconds is just too complicated.

Comment: i know its complicated, i've thought through it but i also believe its possible and it best suits what i want to do, so that i can call the function and alter the settings on the fly via code. without going to the control panel.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, _overcomplicated_. You only have to set up the cronjobs once and then write the PHP code. If you are going to verify the time manually you have the off chance that it just misses the second it needs to run because for whatever reason. Having a 100% guarantee it will run far outweighs the risks you are taking with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close to your goal.

```
// set this to your personal "epoch" from which you want
// all counting to begin
$startdatetime = strtotime('2016-01-01 00:00:00');
$time_advanced = time()-$startdatetime;

$min10 = 60*10;

$t['mins30'] = $min10*3;
$t['mins50'] = $min10*5;
$t['days10'] = $min10*10*24*6;
$t['hours20'] = $min10*20*6;
$t['hours12'] = $min10*10*6;

foreach ($t as $key=>&$time) {
  if ($time_advanced % $time === 0) {
    switch ($key) {
      case 'mins30': A(); break;
      case 'mins50': B(); break;
      case 'days10': C(); break;
      case 'hours20': D(); break;
      case 'hours12': E(); break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome... now you are talking.. let me put it into test and see it work, but i noticed that you are calculating the time yourself,  i was thinking of pointing it to a timeserver to make it very accurate..

Comment: what if you point the server to a time server, keep the accuracy, but relinquish the overhead of the network request?  anyway, let me know how it goes.